# Is the Enterprise the only ship name in the Federation that has such a rich history?

Tags: star-trek

We often see the models of previous Enterprises in the ready room of the captains. Is this the only ship name in the Federation which has such a rich history of use?

I recall in the series Enterprise the Andorian claimed that his ship also have a history of being the pride of their fleet, going back for centuries.

Comment: How about Voyager and the Defiant?  Oh wait you mean history of use as in number of ships that shared the name ;-)

Comment: There was the USS Defiant in the original series episode [The Tholian Web](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Tholian_Web_%28episode%29).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most of the Federation ships that are crewed by majority-human crews have names from actual real-world history (which conveniently is also the canon backstory for ST). In the real world there have been [more ships named USS Enterprise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Enterprise) than on the show, even. So they extended this rich real-world history to in-universe history for the human ships.

There are also [7 USS Saratogas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Saratoga), [2 USS Valiants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Valiant), [4 USS Constellations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Constellation) and [4 USS Intrepids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Intrepid).

Answer (score 6):

Starfleet certainly seems to reuse names in general, not just *Enterprise*. [Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Category%3aFederation_starships) will give you several names that have gotten three uses (even not counting mirror universe or alt-universe versions): *Defiant*, *Saratoga*, *Intrepid*, *Valiant*, and probably a few that I'm missing. There aren't any that I can see which have gotten more than three, but you could easily imagine that to be a matter of show focus, not a fact about the world.

Comment: Just looking at names recycled from historical warships you'll find several examples, e.g. [HMS Reliance (1793)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Reliance_%281793%29). Just google.

Comment: @dmckee Yes, most of the names come from real ship, with a few exceptions like the Defiant.

Comment: @MarkBeadles: That one too http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Defiance . Ooohh and that links to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Defiance . All of which is perfectly reasonable. Navies like traditions and there is no reason to expect that to change.

Comment: Defiant =/= Defiance, but close enough I guess. Also it allows the producers/writers to have a rich history for their ships without having to invent them.

Comment: D'oh! Not close enough. I was fooled by my browser auto-completeing google searches.