# Should the name "Enterprise" have been retired?

Tags: star-trek, uss-enterprise

Obviously "Enterprise" is pretty much synonymous with "Star Trek", so new shows and movies will continue to have an Enterprise.

However, in-universe, how many times does a ship of a given name need to be blown up before it would be considered unlucky?  Alternately, hasn't *at least one* of the previous Enterprises been destroyed in such a manner as to merit an honorary retirement of the name?

**Is there an in-universe reason that Starfleet didn't retire the name "Enterprise" after its predecessors suffered less than ideal fates?**

Comment: Starfleet seem to have a tradition of honouring ships that get blowed up, especially when it's in valorous service; http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/USS_Sao_Paulo

Comment: This seems to be unanswerable? Even in universe it'd probably be a big debate.

Comment: Note that [there have been more real-life Enterprises than Star Trek ones](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/16338/1167).

Comment: [we do not close questions just because they don't/may not have a canon answer](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/3014/5184).

Comment: I have hopefully refined the question to allow for factual answers.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson: Yeah I think that's better

Comment: Naming new warships after lost warships is a long standing naval tradition. It gives crews pride and a sense of history and it confuses the enemy because they can't be sure if certain vessel really sank since radio traffic would still reference the suspect vessels by name or number.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Given that we have at least two in-universe descriptions of why ships are subsequently named (e.g. after vessels that have been destroyed) I'm reasonably certain this should be reopened.

Comment: This question should definitely be re-opened; it is asking for an in-universe reason why the name wasn't retired given its bad luck.  Whether the answer can be answered in canon is beside the point - it is a perfectly reasonable question given the scope of this site.  You have my vote to RO

Comment: With the new series, will the ship be called Enterprise? It's supposed to take place 30 years before TNG. The ship couldn't be called Enterprise-C...that was Rachel Garrett's ship.

Comment: Being destroyed repeatedly is not the same as bad luck: most of these destructions are sacrifices and heroic acts: Kirk sacrificing the ship to save Spock, the Enterprise-C sacrificing itself to aid the Klingons, the Enterprise-D trying to save Veridian III,...

Comment: It doesn't work like that in real life. The Royal Navy has had three aircraft carriers called "Ark Royal", despite the first being sunk.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply put:No.  The Enterprise had a storied history in Humanity, even pre-First Contact.  They kept honoring the ship's long history by creating a new one whenever there was a new generation of ships.  It's almost always been the flagship of Starfleet, and is known by several species outside of the Federation.

Also, can you think of a ship that wasn't destroyed that wasn't rebuilt later on in history?  An example of a ship being re-commissioned would be the *Missouri*. It became a museum for the attack on Pearl Harbor, then in 2010 a submarine was commissioned with the same name.  Also, the USS Wasp was sunk in WW2, and later on another ship was commissioned the Wasp.

Out of universe: Keeping the name Enterprise helps make it familiar with fans, and to show off the progression of technology of the federation.

Comment: While the USS Enterprise (CV-6) survived WW2, the USS Hornet (CV-8) was sunk and quickly replaced 8 months later with the USS Hornet (CV-12).  Other carriers quickly replaced with a new namesake were the USS Wasp (as you mentioned, CV-7 replaced with CV-18), USS Yorktown (CV-5 replaced with CV-10), and USS Lexington (CV-2 replaced with CV-16).  This caused much confusion for the Japanese, who thought they had sunk various carriers to find a new one with the same name.

Comment: Additionally it was mentioned in the films itself that the A Enterprise got its name in honor of the doings of the (non A) Enterprise. It was to honor kirk and thus all later crews